# Describe as a system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

How is it possible to describe the $\dfrac{du_c}{dt}$ and $\dfrac{di}{dt}$ as a
system of differential-equations?

$$ 
u_s = u_r + u_l + u_c\\
i = C\frac{du_c}{dt}\\
u_l = L\frac{di}{dt}\\
u_r = Ri\\
$$

Comment: Yes it's an RLC circuit in series.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).